# Extensive logging of incoming API requests without affecting performance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, rest, iis

I'm developing a rest based API. For each request to the API I want to log a lot of information about that particular request- like who did the request, what resource did he ask for, keep track of how many times this client has asked for this resource, what information is he interested in and much more.

How can I do this without affecting the response time for each request? My idea is to write all this log info to Cache and set the cache expire time to 5 minutes. All incoming request within these 5 minutes will then be written to the same cache object. When the cache expires (It is possible to get a callback when it happens) I will write it to database.

Do you see any drawbacks of this method? Do you have a better suggestion?

PS! Using the built in IIS logging capabilities is not an option as it is not specific enough.

**Update:**
What I'm actually asking here is if there is any well known problems with doing database accesses in the CacheItemRemoved callback? Is it a bad idea?

Comment: Did you think about writing it in asynchronous manner? Use worker thread to do this.

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought, but I read somewhere that it was not a good idea to spawn worker threads from asp.net. But maybe that isn't correct?

Comment: It could be a problem if you will use asp.net threads or if your logging will cause end of thred pool. But, by the way, is your logging affects performance if you log in request thread? Did you measure performance hit?

Comment: Have you consider framework like Log4Net. It has lot many setting where you can control caching and it can store in rolling file as well as database.

Comment: Thanks for the Log4Net tip. It looks really interesting, but for this project I don't want to add more dependencies than absolutely needed. If there is no well known pitfalls to my solution I think I will stick to that.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronously writing is definitely the way to go.  Your proposed solution is complicated and not particularly efficient.  If you don't care about writing to your log in order, the simplest thing to do would be to fire off a logging task like:

```
Task.Run(() => logger.Log("stuff"));
```

If order matters, you might also consider using an ActionBlock.  See [Stephen Cleary's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12121278/607701) in a related SO question.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will consider this. It is important to write the log in Order so I will have to use the ActionBlock. So there is no problems with creating new Threads in asp.net? I read somewhere that you should avoid that. But it may only be a problem if you use the ThreadPool? Why do you mean that my solution is not efficient?